# Select dropdown box invisible top

Tags: html, css

This is the structure of my html:

```html
<!-- modal -->
<div>
    <!-- modal header -->
    <div>

    </div>
    <!-- modal body -->
    <div>
        <select multiple></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the select has a lot of options, when the dropdown box appears I can see some values, but the values on the top of the list I cannot, Some are getting covered by the modal header, and when I removed the modal header I saw more values but some I still cant see the rest, I think they are coming out of the modal but they aren't visible

Comment: Which modal header? please be specific to the modal which you were talking about or better put a working snippet to look over

Comment: It's impossible for us to help you without reproducing your problem ourselves. Please see [ask] and learn how to make a [mre].